# Import file in Jsnonnet/libsonnet application using relative path

Tags: json, import, relative-path, spinnaker, jsonnet

I have a libsonnet file in which I want to import another  libsonnet file proving relative path

I am able to do it by going backward from current folder
For example : import ‘../../../abc.libsonnet’

Is there any way to import same by proving relative path from root folder? Something like below
import ‘./appl/example/test/abc.libsonnet

I tried this but facing ‘No match locally’ error during runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you already found, `import` paths are resolved from:

- the current directory
- the directory of the jsonnet source file importing it

> You can *add* a another directory to the *CLI* by:

- Using the `-J` arg as:

  ```bash
  jsonnet -J <ROOT_DIR> ...
  ```
- pre-exporting below env var:

  ```bash
  env JSONNET_PATH=<ROOT_DIR> jsonnet ...
  ```

> In your case, this could be either

- still relative:

  ```bash
  $ jsonnet -J "${PWD}/../../../" ...
  ```
- "resolve" the relative path:

  ```bash
  $ jsonnet -J "$(realpath ../../../)" ...
  ```

Find more details at: https://www.mankier.com/1/jsonnet#Environment